# Web service using C# PureMVC framework

Tags: c#, web-services, puremvc

I am developing a web service in C# using the C# port of the PureMVC framework. The web service uses nHibernate to connect to and manipulate the database. I have tried to find information about how PureMVC should be initialized when used to manage a web service or if I call a seperate page to invoke PureMVC and have it load the .asmx file directly and pass it the post data. I'm somewhat lost when it comes to the load order so if anyone could help me out with this it would be very appeciated.

Gary

Comment: Well, not too sure about PureMVC but in almost any situation, why dont you use a WCF Service?  ASMX is a thing of the past my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that WCF has a messaging system that appears to run asynchronously. This seems to much better fit the asynchronous nature of Proxies in PureMVC and indicates that I would access the web services as normal where I then instantiate PureMVC and use it to encapsulate my data and commands, I can then query nHibernate and notify the rest of my system when I get a response. This should allow me to create return data objects and send them back through the web services.

If anything about that sounds crazy, please let me know before I invest time implementing it :D

Thanks guys, and thanks to CrazyDart for his input.